# React component is not being rerendered after moving connect to different file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react app I have a component which was exported using react-redux connect.

```
class Test extends Component {
...
}
export default connect(...)(Test)
```

**and using component**:

```
<div>
<Test />
</div>
```

As long as I was exporting it in the same file everything was working fine. Because of tests issue I moved the connect to different file. Now it's like:
(Test.js)

```
class Test extends Component {
...
}
export default Test
```

and in different file (TestConnect.js):

```
import Test from './Test'
...
export default connect(...)(Test)
```

and using component:

```
<div>
<TestConnect />
</div>
```

As long as I had the Component and its connect in the same file changing props was rerendering the Test component. Now it's not. Could You please help me understanding that? How can I fix this?

**Edit**

Solved by use {pure:false} as "options" in connect!

Comment: Can you clear up why you need to separate them?

Comment: Especially because of integration/unit testing. But it's also kind of request from my coworker, so I can't change that.

Comment: Make sure you're importing the right Test Component as this should work. To get around the issue with unit testing you can export the class AND the connected component. This is so you can test the connected and unconnected component.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're actually facing an edge case and this is the only way out, as stated in [`redux's` troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux), using `{pure: false}` isn't the best solution, since `redux` expects your components to be pure (Always produce the same results, given the same `props` and `states`)

Here's how I'd do it:

**Test.js**

```
class Test extends Component {
  ...
  render() { ... } 
}
export default Test
```

**TestContainer.js**

```
import Test from './Test'
import connect from 'react-redux'

class TestContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return(<Test {...this.props} /> (Don't forget to pass your props down, otherwise, Test won't work properly)
  }
}

TestContainer = connect(...)(Test)
export default TestContainer
```

**App.js**

```
import TestContainer from './TestContainer'

class App extends Component {
  ...
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <TestContainer {...props (If you need to pass anything that isn't at redux store)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I've used this approach quite a few times in some projects and it's worked pretty well

If you're not in that edge case scenario and this solution still doesn't work, need some more information to see where things are going wrong :)

Comment: Hm, maybe You are right! I have to check it! Thanks!